# how to add a discount for specific products? Shopping cart price rules

Tags: magento-1.9

I can code in PHP and Laravel alright, so the snippet should not be difficult but I am new to Magento.
I have been tasked with the request of coding a snippet that would give a 20% discount on black Friday for some items identified by the code. The thing is that I have no idea where to look at to start studying the code. On reading papers here and there, it seems that there is not even a need to code as Magento offers that ability, but how can I say, apply the discount to products whose code is between 100 and 200?

I am reading this tutorial (Shopping cart price rule)
http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/shopping-cart-price-rules-in-magento-walk-through/

which is very close to what I want, but here it offers discount if you spend at least 99 dollars. What I want is to offer discount for the products whose ID number is between 100 and 200

Comment: You need quantity of products in cart?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html might be helpful to start

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Gopal, this is the direction I mean. I will read the tut to see if I find how to apply it to products with ID codes.

Comment: You can also check this link it will help you : https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-easily-manage-promotions-and-create-flexible-rules/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this from admin :

> Login to Admin
>
> Go to Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules
>
> Click Add New Rule
>
> Fill Rule Information
>
> On left sidebar, click Conditions tab
>
> Click + button icon
>
> Select Product attribute combination
>
> Click + button icon
>
> Select SKU
>
> Now, you will see SKU is ...
>
> Put your product SKU

Note : SKU option may not show up by default. (Go to: catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes. Then search for the SKU attribute and set the drop down ‘Use for Promo Rule Conditions’ to YES and reindex if needed.)

After above steps set action :

> You can set how much discount you want to give from here
>
> Save Rule

Comment: that is wonderful! will it allow me to set a range of SKU numbers? I mean, I cannot enter all one by one, but would need to state, for all products whose SKU number is between 100 and 200 for example?

Comment: no you can't set SKU range but you can add every SKU in condition

Comment: I got it! thank you!